# Credit Card Number Validator Function [Python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a Starter in Python programming , and I took the challenge I found in the internet ( Credit Card Number Validator {Luhn Algorithm} ) and i wrote this Function :

```
def CheckNumber(CreditCardNumber) :
    CheckNumberBool = False
    CreditCardNumber = list(map(int, CreditCardNumber))
    x = 1
    y = 0
    WorkingList = list()
    #--------------------------------------------------#
    while x <= 15 :
        WorkingList[x].append(CreditCardNumber[x] * 2)
        x += 2
    #--------------------------------------------------#
    while y <= 15 :
        WorkingList[y].append(CreditCardNumber[y])
        y += 2
    #--------------------------------------------------#
    WorkingListStr = str(sum(WorkingList))
    #--------------------------------------------------#
    while y <= 15 :
        if WorkingList[y] >= 10 :
            for x in WorkingListStr :
                WorkingList.append(int(x))
        y += 1
    #--------------------------------------------------#
    if sum(WorkingList) % 10 == 0 :
        CheckNumberBool = True
        print("This is a Valid Credit Card Number")
    else :
        CheckNumberBool = False
        print("This isn't a Valid Credit Card Number")
```

But the problem is that when i run it in my Terminal Command Line (python3 myfile.py) , I get this error :

```
  File "Credit_Card_Algorithm.py", line 13, in CheckNumber
WorkingList[x].append(CreditCardNumber[x] * 2)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thanks to all of your very helpful suggestions and sorry if i made a mistake , this is my first time writing to the huge StackOverflow Community ;-D

Comment: fix the indentations

Comment: I fixed the indentations in my Text Editor but i didn't copied it in the right way , I'm sorry , It is my first time doing this ;-(

Comment: `WorkingList` doesn't look like a list of list, so doing `WorkingList[x].append` makes no apparent sense. You want to append to the list itself so there is no need to retrieve any element, just do `WorkingList.append(..)`

Comment: `WorkingList` is an empty list. `x = 1` => `list()[1]` will raise `IndexError`. Add some elements to the list before accessing them. Anyway the whole code is kind of messy: `WorkingList[x].append` vs `WorkingList.append` meaning that `WorkingList` will contain non homogeneous objects (lists, ints).

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer , have you got any suggestions on how to make my code cleaner ?